# Converting a weird list into a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I scrapped a table from a web page using this code,

```
library(XML)

url2 <- "http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/"

data2 <- readHTMLTable(url2, stringAsFactor = FALSE)
```

It gave me a list which looks something like this,

```
$teams_team_wins3000
    Year   G ARI ATL BLA BAL BOS CHC CHW CIN CLE COL DET HOU KCR ANA LAD FLA
1   2016 149  62  57      81  84  94  72  62  86  71  78  78  75  64  84  73
2   2015 162  79  67      81  78  97  76  64  81  68  74  86  95  85  92  71
3   2014 162  64  79      96  71  73  73  76  85  66  90  70  89  98  94  77
4   2013 163  81  96      85  97  66  63  90  92  74  93  51  86  78  92  62
5   2012 162  81  94      93  69  61  85  97  68  64  88  55  72  89  86  69
6   2011 162  94  89      69  90  71  79  79  80  73  95  56  71  86  82  72
7   2010 162  65  91      66  89  75  88  91  69  83  81  76  67  80  80  80
8   2009 163  70  86      64  95  83  79  78  65  92  86  74  65  97  95  87
9   2008 163  82  72      68  95  97  89  74  81  74  74  86  75 100  84  84
```

If you'd like you can simply copy the code on top to get the same table. The problem is that R is reading this like a list, and I want it to be a data frame.

Normally, I would use this code to convert it into a data frame, but it's not working this time.

```
do.call(rbind, data2) %>% as.data.frame
```

I'm still fairly new to R, and what I would like to do is convert this list into a data frame so that I can then structure the data to look something like this,

```
Year Team Wins Games
2016 ARI  62   149 
2016 ATL  57   149
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: So are you saying that the list has one entry, or multiple entries?

Comment: Can you please show the dput of a small reproducible example

Comment: Maybe I did not get the question right, but the single element in this list is just  a dataframe. 
`class(data2$teams_team_wins3000 ); head(data2$teams_team_wins3000)`
So you can simply use it `head( data2[[1]] )`

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. Basically, my question is why, is R reading this as a list. When I type 'is.data.frame(data2)' it will give me FALSE. But, when I do that with is.list(data2), it gives me TRUE. Your code generated [1] "data.frame". I'm still new to R and I will acknowledge that I've never encountered a problem like this one.

Comment: you could  do ` str(data2) ` to get a quick idea of the structure of data2. Though the output gets too long at times for my comfort

Comment: if you must get input as a dataframe directly, you could try something like `data2 <- as.data.frame(readHTMLTable(url2, stringAsFactor = FALSE))` . This should return a dataframe. Also, I suggest you checkout [tibble](https://github.com/hadley/tibble) for `str(data2)` style insights.

Comment: @Aramis7d Thanks, this returned a data frame. I'll definitely check it out thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems. Spelling: It's `stringsAsFactors`. There *is* a dataframe in there, but because the function is prepared to accept multiple tables it is in there as a list item. You can get it back with "[[" just as you would for any list:

```
str(data2[[1]])
'data.frame':   120 obs. of  33 variables:
 $ Year: Factor w/ 117 levels "1901","1902",..: 116 115 114 113 112 111 110 109 108 107 ...
 $ G   : Factor w/ 15 levels "111","117","129",..: 6 12 12 13 12 12 12 13 13 13 ...
 $ ARI : Factor w/ 19 levels "","100","51",..: 4 10 5 11 11 17 6 7 12 15 ...
 $ ATL : Factor w/ 55 levels "101","103","104",..: 16 26 37 53 51 46 48 44 31 42 ...
 $ BLA : Factor w/ 4 levels "","50","68","BLA": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ BAL : Factor w/ 53 levels "100","101","102",..: 37 37 50 40 47 26 23 21 25 26 ...
 $ BOS : Factor w/ 51 levels "101","104","105",..: 35 29 22 48 21 41 40 46 46 47 ...
 $ CHC : Factor w/ 47 levels "100","104","107",..: 42 44 21 14 10 19 23 31 44 33 ...
 $ CHW : Factor w/ 46 levels "100","49","51",..: 20 24 21 11 32 27 35 27 36 20 ...
 $ CIN : Factor w/ 45 levels "100","102","108",..: 10 11 22 36 42 25 37 24 20 18 ...
 $ CLE : Factor w/ 44 levels "100","111","51",..: 31 26 30 37 13 25 14 10 26 40 ...
 snipped rest of the 33 columns
```

Try:

```
data2 <- readHTMLTable(url2,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(data2[[1]])
```